# Sending SSL HTTP request via TcpClient socket in C#

Tags: c#, sockets, ssl, https, webrequest

I am facing a problem that I must retrieve a website content via a TcpClient socket (I cannot use HttpWebRequest as well as HttpWebResponse because some other issues). I can successfully request to web server using HTTP protocol. But there some webs only accept HTTP SSL request, not the HTTP.
My question is: How can I send HTTP SSL request to the host server and retrieve back the content?

Any advices are really appreciated.

Thanks and best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this [Secure Socket Library](http://www.mentalis.org/soft/projects/ssocket/) and this [class](http://www.mentalis.org/soft/projects/seclib/docs/Org.Mentalis.Security.Ssl.SecureTcpClient.html)

Comment: I am happy with your answer. Thanks you so much!

Answer (score 2):

[SslStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream.aspx) class in .NET framework, or the [SSL/TLS components of SecureBlackbox](https://www.secureblackbox.com/sbb/SSLBlackbox), which my company maintains, if you need advanced functionality and complete control.